# How are there are 16 relations on a two element set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $A=[{a_{1}, a_{2}}]$

I can only think of four those being [(${a_{1}, a_{2}}$), (${a_{2}, a_{1}}$), (${a_{1}, a_{1}}$), (${a_{2}, a_{2}}$)]

supposedly there 16 relations and All but three relations on a two element set are transitive.

if you have any hints on how to figure out the other relations please let me know. I will be working figuring it out too. Thank you.

Comment: A relation on $A$ is a subset of the Cartesian product $A\times A$. How many elements does $A\times A$ have?  How many subsets?

Answer (score 3):

Recall the definition:

> $R$ is a relation on a set $A$ if and only if $R\subseteq A\times A$.

Now ask yourself, how many elements, and therefore how many subsets, does $A\times A$ have?

Comment: well if A is a two element set then $A x A$ has atleast 8 elements which I have found: $(a_{1},a_{2}), (a_{1},a_{1}), (a_{2},a_{2}), (a_{2},a_{1}), (a_{1},\emptyset), (\emptyset, a_{1}), (\emptyset, a_{2}), (a_{2},\emptyset)$

Comment: If $A$ has only two elements, $a_1$ and $a_2$, I don't know why $\varnothing$ appears in your ordered pairs.

Comment: then $AxA$ can only have four element then.@asafkaragila

Comment: Hold on! i think a light bulb went off!!

Comment: Went off or went on?

Comment: I mean went on! english language semantics :(

Comment: does order of elements matter in a relation?

Comment: In a single ordered pair, the order matters. If you have several ordered pair in a single set, then the order you write *in that set* does not matter. Namely, $(a,b)\neq (b,a)$ (at least when $a\neq b$), however $\{a,b\}=\{b,a\}$.

Comment: then $AXA$ has 16 elements sure but many of these relations are repeats since ordering of elements do not matter.

Comment: You keep confusing elements and subsets.

Comment: i fixed the comment now

Comment: No. You haven't. $A\times A$ has four elements, and therefore it has $16$ subsets. What it does not have is both four elements and $16$ elements at the same time. But if that's what you wanted to say, then you have the correct reasoning after all.

Comment: so i listed all 16 subsets of $AXA$ but the meat of the my question is this: Are these two subsets equivalent? $((a_{2},a_{1}), (a_{2},a_{2}), (a_{1},a_{1}), (a_{1},a_{2}))$ $\equiv$ $((a_{2},a_{2}), (a_{1},a_{1}), (a_{1},a_{2}), (a_{2},a_{1}))$

Comment: do you think  you can lend a hand as to what relations out of this 16 are not transitive? I am getting confused because idk how $xRy \land yRz \implies xRz$ relates to this conversation. because it should be obvious that the example of transitivity is not a perfect match for this problem. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: A relation on $A$ is a *subset* of $A\times A$. In general not an element as you seem to think.

Comment: Ha! One second! :-)